# Is there a way to auto-update python auto-docstrings with new/modified parameters?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, docstring

I am using **VS Code** as my editor and **autoDocstring** as the auto-docstring generator extension for **Python**. There are times when I modify the parameters of a function, either by introducing new parameters or by modifying their names, default values etc. I am required to make manual changes to the docstring in such cases.

Is there any way that the docstring gets auto-updated as I change the function signature? At least the introduction of new parameters to the docstring section.

Comment: why not create a PR for the extension, implement the behavior you want

Comment: If you use the IDE's builtin refactor it should inspect docstrings and comments and offer to update them.

Comment: @bad_coder - I am using VS Code. I tried the refactor facility in there but nothing happened. Could you please provide an example with maybe a few screenshots? Any editor in which you might have found the result will do.

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty PyCharm will catch the names, but won't refactor the types, or descriptions automatically.

Comment: If using sphinx to generate html for the docs, there are a lot of plugins that can avoid the duplication (and therefore the human error). E.g. [default-values](https://default-values.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) allows injecting the default value into the generated docs, and [sphinx-autodoc-typehints](https://github.com/tox-dev/sphinx-autodoc-typehints?tab=readme-ov-file) can convert the type hints into the docs as well. In these cases, all you need to do is make sure the name matches, and the rest will follow.

Comment: @flakes, but that's for generated documentation, what about simple docstrings of functions? My gut feeling is that this should be very straightforward and the functionality probably exists, I simply don't know what words I have to look for.