# Is there something like "f-docstring"?

Tags: python, docstring

I want to mention default values for function arguments in the function descriptions (docstrings).
What I don't want to do is to manually edit the docstrings, whenever I try out new default values

So, is there something like f-docstrings, that enables dynamically updating the decstrings content ?

I tried

```py
def check_availability(self, checks: int = 10, timeout: float = 1.5, apply_filters: bool = False) -> list[dict]:
    f'''
    Checks which proxies on "https://free-proxy-list.net/" are really available 
    by requesting visible IP returned by "http://icanhazip.com"  

    Args:
        checks (int): amount of checks, corresponds to the first entries in the considered proxies list); defaults to {checks}
        timeout (float): accepted response waiting time in seconds.
        apply_filters (bool): If True a before generated filtered proxies list is considered for the checks, otherwise the entire list is considered.

    Returns:
        list[dict]: list of confirmed proxies
    '''
```

When I hover over a call of that method I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwoDD.png)

This is how it shouldf look like:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72065313/5133585

Comment: Just tried to highlight the relevant parts of the code sniplet above, but failed.
Hints on that would also be welcome ;)

Comment: I don't think so. f-strings rely on runtime data, which your IDE cannot have.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans
Thanks, but I guess this example is to high-level for my basic understanding in PYthon. Maybe I could understand it if there would be default values in the example.

Comment: You shouldn't, the convention is to put `checks : int, optional` without the actual default value. Have a look some open source libraries for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever I try out new default values

Two things:

1. When experimenting, just pass the actual values to the function rather than updating the default values every time. These are function arguments for a reason.
2. In the screenshot you provided, the default values are clearly visible outside the docstring, in the method definition. You might consider omitting default values from the docstring entirely, since they're visible in the method declaration.